# How to work in trunk and branch at the same time?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, branching-and-merging

I've reading and testing subversion (through `TortoiseSVN`) branching and merging system and there I can't completely understand it.

I have a project `MyProject` with a `src` directory in its root. Using the `TFS` I could make a branch from it call it `big-dev-src` and then have (in the root directory) both `src` (trunk) and `big-dev-src` (branch). I could `update / get latest version` of any, `commit / check in` to any and `merge` them (branch to merge or vice-versa). And both were completely independent.

Now, using `subversion` it seems like I need to do a `switch` operation to change from one to the other and, if I have pending changes the `switch` will `merge` them.

Am I understanding something wrong? Is there anyway to use it somehow like the `TFS` works?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you have two working copies, or even a single working copy checked out from the common parent? Then perform merges between them as needed.

Comment: Two working copies is the solution suggested by Lazy Badger. I don't love that idea and I'm not sure how would I be able to manage it between multiples PCs. About the single working copy checked out from the parent (actually from the repository root) its what I would like but I've been having trouble to make the merge. Maybe the merging process is what I'm not understanding well

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like I need to do a switch operation to change from one to the other

You *can* switch (or don't switch), just because you can have any amount of Working Copies for any amount of related Repository-URLs

With "WC per URL" (one for trunk, one for every WIP-branch) you can have completely independent work

PS: You can also checkout repo-root (bad idea in common sense, but it's possible)

```
>dir /B
branches
readme.textile
tags
trunk

>svn info
....
Relative URL: ^/
...
```

Comment: How or where do I set "WC per URL"?

Comment: @Diego - just DOIT! `cd DIR1; svn co URL1; cd DIR2; svn co URL2`

Comment: Ok, I think I understood. I would be having "two different clients" of the repository but one would be insider the other and its root wont be the root of the repository?

Comment: @Diego - yes, so-so

Answer (score 0):

There is a best-practice project structure which looks like this:

```
myproject
|- trunk       (main line of development, in your case: src)
|- branches
|  |- big-dev  (your big-dev-src)
|  :
`- tags
```

Of course, this is only a suggestion which is not enforced in any way; branches are copies, from the Subversion point of view.

Despite the additional "directory level" it is perfectly possible to have working copies of the trunk and a branch in the same parent directory, and change them synchroneously:

```
# svn checkout svn://svn.myserver/myproject/trunk src
# svn checkout svn://svn.myserver/myproject/branches/big-dev big-dev-src
```

You can make similar changes in both of them and commit them in one revision (although you'd do so only for very simple changes):

```
# cd src
# svn commit . ../big-dev-src
```

You can merge changes from one directory tree to the other, of course.
However, if you use non-urls to merge from, you must specify the revisions (`-c` or `-r` options). You should isolate merges from other changes (i.e., always merge to a clean working copy without any unversioned changes, and first commit the merge result before changing anything else) and use the `--record-only` option to tell the branch about its changes which have already made it to the trunk.

Comment: Reading again my question made me realize that it might be a bit confusing. I don't need the trunk and branch to be independent like they are when using two different working copies (two different `checkouts`). My question is because I read that to work with a branch I should run the `Switch` operation. I tried it and it was really confusing, I started working for the branch in the trunk directory.